# How to convert JPG file to binary string?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, upload, ksoap2

I wanna upload a jpg file from android to server using asp.net web service with ksoap2 library.
I searched to net and found noting, Now i just can convert jpg file to binary and send string file and in server convert to jpg file

Somebody please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/muditsen/imageUploadUsingVolley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Base64 Android class:

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```